# Computer crash with utorrent after 30 minutes

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, freeze, crash, utorrent

I have a weird problem in which, if I leave my computer unattended, AND I leave uTorrent open, downloading/seeding, the computer simply crashes after about 20 / 30 minutes (don't know exactly since if I leave it, and come back later, it is crashed.)

If I leave the computer alone for undefined time WITHOUT uTorrent, nothing happens, and if I am constantly using the computer while using uTorrent, no problem either (I could be using it all day with uT open and it doesn't crash).

I have already checked the power management so the computer never enters stand by mode, sleep, hibernate, etc.

Specs: i5 4690k , Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit, 8 GB RAM, samsung evo 840 ssd, Latest version of uTorrent (also happening with previous version.)

Comment: Have you checked the Windows crash log? What does it say?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have checked the usual places for crash logs etc? I had a similar problem some time ago. Utorrent would hang windows for a few minutes and then pc would reboot. I changed my client to transmissionQt and have had no problems at all since.